# How to add NSTextFields to NSScrollView

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsscrollview

I want to add multiple `NSTextField`s to `NSScrollView` dynamically.

**Code:**

```
func addLabel(data: String)
{
    let offset = labelCount*20
    let label = NSTextField(frame: NSMakeRect(0, CGFloat(offset), 200, 20))
    label.stringValue = data
    scrollView.documentView?.addSubview(label)
    labelCount += 1

    // scrollView is IBOutlet
    // labelCount is var to keep record of number of labels
}
```

**Problem:**

It adds the `NSTextField`s correctly to the `NSScrollView` but they are only added till the visible part is available. After the visible part of `NSScrollView` is full, no more `NSTextField`s are added to it.

I need to add `NSTextField`s even though the visible part is full and scroll to find others.

How can I do it?

Comment: Find out what the documentView property is.

Comment: @ElTomato Do you mean what it's type? If it is, then it's type is `NSView`.

Comment: @ElTomato When I print subviews of `scrollView.documentView!.subviews` I can get the list of `NSTextField` added to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's something like the following.

```
scrollView.documentView?.setFrameSize(CGSize(width: CGFloat(labelCount) * 200, height: 20))
```

Comment: There is a small problem in the code. 1). I'm scrolling vertically so `CGSize(width: 469, height: CGFloat(labelCount) * 200 )`. 2). Increasing that much of size adds unnecessary empty scrollable space. So, `CGSize(width: 469, height: CGFloat(labelCount) * 20 + 20 )`. It sets the frame perfectly without any extra space. Thanks for guiding me in the right direction.